# How to check for an app (native or hybrid)

Tags: android, apk, native, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm working on sauce lab integration with appium, and created a poc for ebay app.
Now the requirement is that the poc should work for native, hybrid and web.
How would i know that which app is native and which is hybrid because I don't have the source code for the app, only have the apk file for automation test.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, there is a simple way to distinguish between hybrid and native app. Go to Developer Options from Settings and turn on Show Layout bounds. And then launch your app and see the layout highlighted. If there are lots of rectangle highlighted, it's native. Otherwise hybrid.

Comment: It is not always true.  For exampple: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marketwatch&hl=en this is a hybrid app but you can see layout bounds.

Comment: Works In most of apps .

Answer (score 0):

Install an apk and check for webview in uiautomator.